# how we can set only outer border for pdfptable using c#.net?

Tags: c#

how we can set only outer border for `pdfptable` using c#.net?

I know `pdfCell` border property, but I want only `pdfptable` full border property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we can set all cell borders as 0 and After assigning all cell to table we can use the following code for only **`pdfptable`** outer border.

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.AddElement(t);
cell.BorderWidthBottom=1f;
cell.BorderWidthLeft=1f;
cell.BorderWidthTop=1f;
cell.BorderWidthRight = 1f;
PdfPTable t1 = new PdfPTable(1);
t1.AddCell(cell);
```

Here we can add table to one cell and can set border and again add that cell to another table and we can use as per our requirement.

Comment: @Jom_George Error showing as 't' does not exist in current context.